# Magento 1.9.1.0 update PHP & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, magento, upgrade, virtualmin

I have an installation of magento 1.9.1.0 in a dedicated server with virtual min.Everything works ok but I noticed that my server runs Mysql version 5.1.73 and PHP version 5.3.3 . I want to update them in what magento suggests. Will I have problems with the site?
I want to upgrade to PHP 5.5 and Mysql 5.6 but I am afraid for my existing site if it works after the upgrade.
Can anyone help?
Thank you

Comment: Note that marking an answer as accepted is the way to indicate the question is solved, do not edit it with "solved" in the title : )

Comment: Thank you and sorry for that....I am new here and I am learning.

Comment: No problem : ) You may want to read [ask] for further information.

Comment: I will do....thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento version 1.9.1.0 direectly supports PHP 5.4 & 5.5 http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements and http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements for previous requirements.  As you can see, Magento also supports MySQL 5.6 (and many of our stores run it, or Percona).

Comment: I know that magento supports these versions....The thing is if I upgrade the server with these versions will magento continue to work? I never did that before

Comment: Yes. Magento supports these versions, so as long as you upgrade and MySQL 5.6 and PHP 5.5 work, then you won't have any problems with Magento.